# sqlalchemy event firing multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, sqlalchemy

```
# SQLAlchemy Events / Handlers
@event.listens_for(User.first_name, "set")
@event.listens_for(User.last_name, "set")
@event.listens_for(User.did, "set")
@event.listens_for(User.email_address, "set")
def update_service(target: User, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    """
    If certain fields are changed in the db, we want to
    propogate those changes to <service>.
    """
    if target.is_thing and oldvalue is not None:
       target.do_thing()
```

This code registers each update as a separate event, resulting in several consecutive update calls to `do_thing()` if the code updates several fields at once. Unfortunately, capturing the update event on the entire User model backfires: It causes our custom primaryjoin logic for the entire model to not run at all. (No idea why this is the case... it also ends up just being called way too often because it gets called whenever the joined tables are updated.)

Is there a pattern that would allow me to register multiple attributes at once for the event? Or is it possible to set a temporary flag on `target` that would persist to other calls of the event?

Comment: You might be better off capturing these changes in a session event, so you can examine the entire instance?

Comment: Doing so seems to cause our custom `primaryjoin=...` logic on the model to simply stop working outright -- any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you should be asking a question about why event listening breaks your join logic then?